# Activity starting product details in same activity (don't want this)

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to show product Details in different activities, so user can hold (don't need to return to main screen more than one product Opened and easily switched btw) then uses the Android Task Manager (Recent Applications):

WHAT I WANT:

[image]

what I have:

[image]

the code I'm using:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
     <activity
android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity="" // must use this or it create just one activity for the application and open the second activity in top of main activity
                android:name=".Activities.ListActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                android:label="Produt List"
                android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"/>


     <activity
                android:name=".Activities.DetailsActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                android:label="Produt Details"
                android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"/>
```

how I open the ActivityDetails:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityDetails.class);
i.putExtra("productID", product.getId());

        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); //must add for BOTH
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK); //must add for both

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){

i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //for new task
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT); //must add for lollipop

}
else{
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
}
startActivity(i);
```

for Android Lollipop it's working, because the NEW_DOCUMENT(if i remove it, it stop working for lollipop too), but for api < api21, its not working =/, just creates the instance of ActivityDetails and all products open in the same activity.  Instead, I want new activities (multiple copies showing different products).

tried using this information: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Comment: you could have a practice to try to understand it using this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.novoda.demos.activitylaunchmode&hl=en

Comment: Hi @Blundell this app show, but it doesnt has all the flags, anyway, can you post what you think? should i try this or handle Fragments showing the Item Details in the second activity and handle the FragmentManager to return to the item he wants? using the (on newIntent)

Comment: You could fork the source code and add the new flags so you can see the desired behaviour you want: https://github.com/gnorsilva/Activities-LaunchMode-demo

Comment: @Blundell thanks, i choose to use Fragments, its easier and better i think